# Replace currency symbol by word in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a file of about 50000 tweets and I want to replace all the currency symbols by words so that `$10` becomes  `10 dollars.`

How can I do that in Python?

I can find the symbols using a regex: `[$][0-9]+`.
I am not sure how to replace that by words and and also interchange the positions of the number and symbol.

My tweets have only `$` symbols and no other currency symbols.
Please help.

Comment: The tweets contains numbers with separators like `1,000` or `1,000.28` ?

Comment: @dot.Py No seperators.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can you please comment why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.sub(..)` is your friend.

```
>>> re.sub(r"\$(\d+)", r"\1 dollars", "$10")
'10 dollars'
```

Comment: won't work if tweet contains a number with thousands or cents separator (i.e.: 1,000.28)

Comment: I do not think that is the case given the regex OP originally constructed.

Comment: should be trivial for the OP to implement.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to put a comment when you downvote?

Comment: @dot.Py Thats a lazy argument. I won't handle it all together, you can just replace ',' with '' before processing.

Comment: @kskp: the `pattern` is wrong. Also, you have got your arguments wrong. remove `pattern` variable and the first parameter in your function. Add a third parameter called: `line`.